# LAMP DB-agnostic way to create a DB stack

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration, mysql, ansible, database

Is there a LAMP-MySQL (or equivalent) **agnostic** way to create a DB stack that includes:

1. DB-user and a relative password
2. DB with the same name as of the user
3. Setting a host for the DB (say, `localhost`)
4. Give the user all privileges

The reason I need such a way or approach is to have easier life when working with different LAMP-MySQL (or equivalent) DB programs as part of LAMP.

For example, not all LAMP stacks has particularly MySQL or MariaDB and the SQL syntax or DB-CLUI (Bash) extension syntax might be a tiny bit different for each DB SQL variant, hence I seek standardization in a LAMP-RDBMS agnostic fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether anything already exists (i.e. in Galaxy), but Ansible certainly provides all the building blocks to do this. A reason this may well not have been done, or at least released publically, is that there is no **one** way to configure a database, much less an agreed method that **any** DB technology should be generally configured. So I would guess you will need to roll this yourself.

As for how to go about doing that, an approach I would likely investigate:

- Write a general DB role, that expects a common series of parameters to be passed to it (i.e. DB technology, default users, default DB's)
- Write a role for each DB technology type, that can be passed only the common parameters. This role would then run the DB technology specific tasks to provision your instance
- Add role dependencies to your general DB role, conditional on the DB technology type

A pseudo example:

playbook.yml

```
---

# Apply the 'db' role to DB hosts
- hosts: db_hosts
  roles:
    - db
```

roles/db/defaults/main.yml

```
---

# Provide a default tech so one does not have to be passed at run time
db_technology: postgresql
```

roles/db/meta/main.yml

```
---

# Include the specific DB tech role, based on the value of 'db_technology'
dependencies:
  - { role: postgresql, db_params: "{{ db_params }}", when: db_technology == 'postgresql' }
  - { role: mysql, db_params: "{{ db_params }}",  when: db_technology == 'mysql' }
```

roles/db/tasks/main.yml

```
---

# Do tasks that are common to all DB types here
```

roles/postgresql/tasks/main.yml

```
---

# Do postgresql specific tasks here
```

roles/mysql/tasks/main.yml

```
---

# Do mysql specific tasks here
```

Finally, this could then be run with:

```
ansible-playbook -e "db_technology=mysql, db_params={'users': {'someuser': 'somepassword'}, 'dbs': ['some_db_name', 'another_db_name']" playbook.yml
```

Please do be aware, this is a very general, very incomplete example to give you an idea of the structure you could use to solve this problem.